# Using Flutter Freezed to generate code to parse a Json Object

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-freezed

I'm trying to parse some JSON from a file and decided to use Freezed to generate the code. The problem is that (as far as i can tell) there's no way to use a JSON object's name.

So say I have the following JSON object:

```
{
  "uniqueName":{
    "website": "https://www.example.com/",
    "description": "Some description",
    "hosted_demo": false,
    "demo": "",
    "oss": false,
    "source": "",
    "other-links": [
      {
        "title": "Clients",
        "site": "https://shlink.io/apps"
      }
    ],
    "license": "MIT"
  }
}
```

Then this would be the required dart code for Freezed code ([done with instructions from this site](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/parse-json-dart-codegen-freezed/)):

```dart
// 1. import freezed_annotation
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

// import any other models we depend on
import 'otherLinks.dart';

// 2. add 'part' files
part 'freezed_files/item.freezed.dart';
part 'generated/item.g.dart';

// 3. add @freezed annotation
@freezed
// 4. define a class with a mixin
class Item with _$Item {
  // 5. define a factory constructor
  factory Item(
      {
      // 6. list all the arguments/properties
      @Default("") String website,
      @Default("") String description,
      // ignore: invalid_annotation_target
      @Default(false) @JsonKey(name: 'hosted_demo') bool? hostedDemo,
      @Default("") String demo,
      @Default(false) bool oss,
      @Default("") String source,
      // ignore: invalid_annotation_target
      @Default([]) @JsonKey(name: 'other-links') List<OtherLinks> otherLinks,
      @Default("") String license
      // 7. assign it with the `_Item` class constructor
      }) = _Item;

  // 8. define another factory constructor to parse from json
  factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ItemFromJson(json);
}
```

But i have no idea how to get the `uniqueName` into the data class. Most other places I've checked assume that the JSON data is formatted with the `uniqueName` inside JSON object with its own key. While refactoring the JSON file is an option, I would rather not. The whole JSON file is about 12000 lines, making refactoring it a pain.

Do you folks have any idea how I can get `uniqueName` into the data class?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this what you're looking for, but how about this?

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

import 'otherLinks.dart';

part 'freezed_files/item.freezed.dart';
part 'generated/item.g.dart';

@freezed
class Item with _$Item {
  factory Item({
    // Add a new property to save the uniqueName
    @Default("") String uniqueName,
    @Default("") String website,
    @Default("") String description,
    @Default(false) @JsonKey(name: 'hosted_demo') bool? hostedDemo,
    @Default("") String demo,
    @Default(false) bool oss,
    @Default("") String source,
    @Default([]) @JsonKey(name: 'other-links') List<OtherLinks> otherLinks,
    @Default("") String license
  }) = _Item;

  factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ItemFromJson(json);

  // Add this new function
  factory Item.fromUniqueJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    // Get the uniqueName string key and save it
    var uniqueNameKey = json.keys.first;

    // Convert the rest of the json object beneath the uniqueName key
    return Item.fromJson(json[uniqueNameKey])
      // Return the new Item with the uniqueName saved as a property
      .copyWith(uniqueName: uniqueNameKey);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'item.freezed.dart';
part 'item.g.dart';

@freezed
class Item with _$Item {
  factory Item({
    @Default(UniqueName) UniqueName uniqueName,
  }) = _Item;

  factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ItemFromJson(json);
}

@freezed
class UniqueName with _$UniqueName {
  factory UniqueName({
    @Default('') String website,
    @Default('') String description,
    @Default(false) bool hostedDemo,
    @Default('') String demo,
    @Default(false) bool oss,
    @Default('') String source,
    @Default([]) @JsonKey(name: 'other-links') List<OtherLink> otherLinks,
    @Default('') String license,
  }) = _UniqueName;

  factory UniqueName.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$UniqueNameFromJson(json);
}

@freezed
class OtherLink with _$OtherLink {
  factory OtherLink({
    @Default('') String title,
    @Default('') String site,
  }) = _OtherLink;

  factory OtherLink.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$OtherLinkFromJson(json);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.